# How to put content of $templateCache.put(...) into html file instead of embedding Html into Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-template, angular-templatecache

Embedding HTML in JavaScript like the following code snippet is not maintainable when you have one file app.js and many modules.

**app.js**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when('/first',{
    templateUrl: 'partial/first.html',
    controller: 'FirstCtrl' 
  });
}]).run(function($templateCache){
     $templateCache.put('partial/first.html', '<p>Hundred lines of Html</p>');
    });
```

Is it possible to migrate these 100 LoC from $templateCache.put(...) into the Html file just like we use templateUrl instead of template? OR suggest another approach to accomplish this because I'm losing control over the code. I want to use *$templateCache* for quick retrieval.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a build script e.g. with [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) to do this kind of thing. There is an npm module called [angular-template-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache) which does exactly what you want.

```
var angularTemplateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache');

gulp.task('compile:templates', () =>
    gulp.src('/src/**/*.html')
        .pipe(angularTemplateCache('templates.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('/dist'))
);
```

This gulp task would create a file `/dist/templates.js` which contains a `$templateCache.put` for each html file under the `src` dir. You can make this part of your build process along with minification, cache busting etc.

Comment: Could you please add the code in your answer so that we can have idea how to achieve the solution.